# Connecting to SQL Server container on Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I write a program in ASP.NET Core with SQL Server database, and I use Docker to containerize my app. But when I start my container on Docker desktop, my app can't connect to the database.

I installed a SQL Server instance on Docker and it runs correctly, but app still can't connect to the database and throws an error 40.

This is my Docker file content:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY dist /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EMS.TrafficRecordService.gRPC.dll"]
```

This is my connection string

```
Server = 127.0.0.1,2019; Database = EMS_TrafficRecord_DB; User Id=SA; Password=mypass@wo0rd; MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
```

This is my command to build the Docker image

```
docker build . -t ems-t-r-s -f Dockerfile
```

And this is my command to create the container:

```
docker create -p 3001:80 --name ems-trs ems-t-r-s
```

Finally, this is my command to run my SQL Server instance on Docker desktop

```
docker run -i -p 2019:1433 -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=mypass@wo0rd -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I can connect to this instance with SSMS, but I can't connect with the connection string in my app.

I Searched in Stack overflow but again I can't find right solution

Comment: Your two containers need to be sharing a network in order to be able to communicate with one another. Otherwise, they are isolated from one another. Docker Compose is one low-effort option to orchestrate multiple container solutions so you can manage everything with a single command. The IP address `127.0.0.1` within a container is going to point to that container's loopback address, not a different container or the host OS.

Comment: @DanielMann what you suggest me to do in this position I'm new to docker and don't know much about it

Comment: I suggest that you use the information that I provided you to do some independent research on how to manage cross-container communication. I suggested Docker Compose. Perhaps reading up on Docker Compose would be a good next step?